# paymentButtonContainer.setup unresolve reference

Tags: android, kotlin, paypal, payment-gateway

for the paymentButtonContainer.setup I get the error of Unresolved reference: paymentButtonContainer. However I have already declare the button container in the xml file as instructed on https://developer.paypal.com/limited-release/paypal-mobile-checkout/android/.

Tried using binding.paymentButtonContainer.setup. However the system crash due to error :

> Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11 in com.example.paypal:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class com.paypal.checkout.paymentbutton.PaymentButtonContainer

Code in MainActivity.kt

```
val config = CheckoutConfig(
            application,
            clientId = "*********my client id***************",
            environment = Environment.SANDBOX,
            currencyCode = CurrencyCode.USD,
            userAction = UserAction.PAY_NOW,
            settingsConfig = SettingsConfig(
                loggingEnabled = true
            )
        )
        PayPalCheckout.setConfig(config)

 paymentButtonContainer.setup(
            createOrder =
            CreateOrder { createOrderActions ->
                val order =
                    Order(
                        intent = OrderIntent.CAPTURE,
                        appContext = AppContext(userAction = UserAction.PAY_NOW),
                        purchaseUnitList =
                        listOf(
                            PurchaseUnit(
                                amount =
                                Amount(currencyCode = CurrencyCode.USD, value = "10.00")
                            )
                        )
                    )
                createOrderActions.create(order)
            },
            onApprove =
            OnApprove { approval ->
                approval.orderActions.capture { captureOrderResult ->
                    Log.i("CaptureOrder", "CaptureOrderResult: $captureOrderResult")
                }
            }
        )
```

code in activity_main.xml

```
<com.paypal.checkout.paymentbutton.PaymentButtonContainer
        android:id="@+id/paymentButtonContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:paypal_button_color="silver"
        app:paypal_button_label="pay"
        app:paypal_button_shape="rectangle"
        app:paypal_button_size="large"
        app:paypal_button_enabled="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try change your implementation in the Gradle file

implementation'com.paypal.checkout:android-sdk:0.8.8'